# Writing a python script to connect to a port

Tags: python, networking

I'm taking Sam Bowne's online class right now and am trying to connect to a port in 1 second. I've figured out how to print the new port number but can't connect:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
s=socket.socket()

i=20001
target= 'packtpub.samsclass.info'

try:
        s.connect((target,int(i)))
        x = s.recv(1024)
        print(x)
        abe = x[24:29]
        print abe

finally:
        print 'Knocking on second port:'
        s.connect(('packtpub.samsclass.info',int(abe)))
        print s.recv(1024)
        s.close()
```

Comment: It should raise syntax errors coz sometimes it seems python3.x and other python2 because of `print`

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect the same socket twice, you need to create a new socket for the second connection.

Also, `finally:` should be `else:`. If there's an error in `try`, it won't assign `abe`, and you can't use that for the second connection. `else:` is only run if there's no error.

But this only makes sense if you also have code for `except:`. If not, you can simply put the later code right after the first code, you don't need `try`.

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
s=socket.socket()

i=20001
target= 'packtpub.samsclass.info'

try:
    s.connect((target,int(i)))
    x = s.recv(1024)
    print(x)
    abe = x[24:29]
    print(abe)
    s.close()

else:
    print 'Knocking on second port:'
    s2 = socket.socket()
    s2.connect((target,int(abe)))
    print(s2.recv(1024))
    s2.close()
```

Comment: I see no reason in `try .. finally` there, if code in `try` won't be executed than finally will throw an error anyway/